# How do I redirect between nginx servers on the same domain?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have two nginx servers A and B. B has a server block for example.com that includes http to https redirect. Now I'd like A to direct traffic for example.com straight to B. I tried the following

In A:

```
upstream ipOfB {
    server 12.34.56.78;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443;
   server_name example.com;
   location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://ipOfB;
   }
}`
```

In B:

```
upstream docker {
    server 0.0.0.0:8080;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name example.com

   location / {
     ...
   }
}
```

I get too many redirects when I try example.com.

Comment: Did you get a solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a server block that listens on port 80 but redirects to 443. Something like the following:

```
upstream example {
    server     localhost:3000;
}

server{
   listen 443;
   server_name example.com;

   ssl on;
   #Other SSL Configuration

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://example;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://example;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
  return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

To test out with free SSL you can check this [article](https://www.attosol.com/implementing-ssl-free-quick/).